# Does yarn ignore .npmignore?

Tags: npm, package, npm-install, yarnpkg

I'm creating a npm package for self-learning purpose and published it on Github repo. The idea is that I want to install the package from one of the branch github repo rather.
My folder contains:

```
a/
b/
c/
.gitignore
.npmignore
package.json
```

I want to ignore certain file so I put them in `.npmignore`:

```
a
c
```

When I `npm install git://github.com/USER/REPO.git#MY_AWESOME_BRANCH` and look into node_modules

```
node_modules
└── MY_PACKAGE_NAME
   ├── b/
   ├── .gitignore
   ├── .npmignore
   └── package.json
```

But when I `yarn add git://github.com/USER/REPO.git#MY_AWESOME_BRANCH`

```
node_modules
└── MY_PACKAGE_NAME
   ├── a/
   ├── b/
   ├── c/
   ├── .gitignore
   ├── .npmignore
   └── package.json
```

Somehow, `yarn add` is ignoring `.npmignore` file. Is there a way to exclude certain files for both `npm install` and `yarn add` ?

Comment: Did you fin a solution?

Comment: If you want to create a package for learning purposes but need finer grained control, publish it to Github packages instead of a Github repo.

Answer (score 3):

TLDR: `.npmignore` has no impact on `yarn install` or `yarn add`.

There's a bit of confusion here on the purpose of the `.npmignore` file. It is not a configuration used when installing a package. It is used when publishing the package. By using a GitHub repository (as opposed to [GitHub Packages](https://docs.github.com/en/packages)), you are essentially publishing everything recognized by Git.

You can use the `.gitignore` file to alter the files that are committed and pushed to your GitHub repository. The `.gitignore` file is also respected as a default when the `.npmignore` is not present in case you choose to publish to a package repository like NPM or GItHub Packages at a later date.

Reference: https://npm.github.io/publishing-pkgs-docs/publishing/the-npmignore-file.html

Comment: The question remains unanswered: _Is there a way to exclude certain files for both `npm install` and `yarn add`?_

Comment: Yes, as I said, you can use the `.gitignore` file to not PUSH the files to Github. If the Github repo is the package repo, then pushing to Github equates to publishing the files.

The config files in question are for configuring publishing. NOT downloading. If you want to use the package, you download all the files published for that package. That's it.